# using facebook api to get user data. php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

I have been trying to get `user checkins friend checkins user locations friends locations` etc. 
My goal is to get user specific locations when they login. Like the establishment they are at.

Everything I use to accomplish this is not working correctly.

I use location and all the geo information comes up or address.

I use checkins and random ones pop up. But not the most recent ones.

I read this

Endpoints no longer available in v2.0

```
/me/locations has been removed. Please use /me/tagged_places instead.
```

But when I try to use 
`/me/tagged_places` it does not work 
`My var_dump($variable)` gives me `NULL`

Here is my current code.

```
    $user_info      = $facebook->api('/' . $user);
    $user_tags      = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/tagged_places');
    $friends            = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/friends');
    $user_feed          = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/feed/?with=location');
    $friends_locations  = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/friends/?fields=location');
    $user_checkins      = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/checkins');
    $friends_checkins   = $facebook->api('/' . $user . '/friends/checkins');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add the graph version to the URL with the SDK version you're using:

```
$user_info = $facebook->api('/v2.0/' . $user);
```

Or upgrade to the new SDK v4:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4

Comment: When I download this new version is there no longer a facebook.php file I can require? I can't figure oitnwhat to include in to my project now to get this to work.

Comment: Using Composer or another autoloader is the easiest, but you can require the files you need directly.

Comment: Where can I look up what files I need to require for what ever purposes? For instance does each permission require a different set of files?

Comment: It depends what classes you decide to use... typically, FacebookSession, FacebookRequest, GraphObject.